# Using grid layout manager on a tkinter canvas

Tags: layout, grid, tkinter, widget

I want to draw some lines & add several text widget (textbox) on a canvas 
at the same time (in python tkinter library). How can I use grid layout manager 
instead of only calling canvas.create_window function?

Comment: @furas: you can use it (as in, you won't get errors), but if you use grid, the items won't scroll and any lines drawn will always be below the widgets.

Comment: @Bryan Oakley It seems I write it to briefly :) Probably I should write `You can't use "grid" in place of "create_window" to get expected result`. But your comment is good for answer.